# version mismatches on boost library

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

I want to replace old boost 1.49 with new one boost 1.55 in my ubuntu system so, I installed boost 1.55 from the official web site. 
However, there still exist some mismatches as follows.

Below program prints "Boost version: 1_49"

```
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Boost version: " << BOOST_LIB_VERSION << endl;
   retrun 0;
}
```

But, this command prints

```
$ cat /usr/include/boost/version.hpp | grep "BOOST_LIB_VERSION"
//    BOOST_LIB_VERSION must be defined to be the same as BOOST_VERSION
#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_55"
```

I want to force all relevant programs to the boost libraries to use the new version of boost library as default. What should I do for that purpose? thanks in advance.

Comment: What are "all relevant programs"? Do you need to keep 1.49? If not, remove it.

Comment: Check your include path

Comment: The programs that use boost library. As you said, I moved boost files to some directory by following this instructions [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=892951). However, my program still prints "Boost version: 1_49". 
How can I check my include path?